# How can I control the apps on my Android phone from a Win 10 laptop?

Tags: android, windows-10

I use Chrome Remote Desktop to control my laptop in every way from my phone. Now, I'm looking for an app that t I can control my S6 phone from my laptop? I want to be able to view my phone screen on my laptop and be able  to manipulate evey aspect of the phone.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware if there is app to do what you want remotely, but Vysor is an option.

What you require is the [Vysor app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.vysor&hl=en), the [Vysor chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm) (yes, this only works on Google Chrome), a USB cable, and ADB drivers if you are using Windows.

To use it, install the app and the extension, and make sure that you are connected to the phone via USB. Launch the Chrome extension after this.

Fair warning, you need to purchase the Pro version for quite a few of its features and my experience with it hasn't been bug free.

Comment: You can find ADB drivers for Windows [here](https://adb.clockworkmod.com/) (this link was provided by the app itself).

Answer (score 0):

You can install teamviewer in phone andd PC, also you can try many other remote control apps that do the same thing.

Comment: Teamviewer is too complicated for me.